# Simultaneous confidence intervals for multinomial proportions: pooling replicates or not?

Tags: confidence-interval, bootstrap, multinomial-distribution, proportion

I observed 21 times a response that could be one out of 8 categories (multinomial response). I computed the proportions for each category.
I did it independently 12 times. Hence I have 12 replicates for each proportion.
Is bootstrapping the mean proportion over the 12 replicates for getting the confidence interval a good idea?

I tried (see codes below) and got some very large confidence intervals. Actually, according to the bootstrapped CI, there are no significant differences in proportions, while a chi-square test on pooled proportions (over replicates) confirms that there are differences.

So, do I have to pool my proportions or not?

If I have to, do you know an R function for computing Simultaneous confidence intervals for multinomial proportions?

If I am able to keep replicates, is bootstrapping as done below OK?

```
# generation of a data set: multinomial réponse variable repeatedly measured
sub<-c("s1","s2","s3","s4")#subject
per<-c("p1","P2","p3")#period, RM within subject
tim<-paste("t",1:21,sep="")#tim, RM within period
mydata<-expand.grid(tim=tim,per=per,sub=sub)
#for simplicity, let's consider that period is not a repeated measure
#within subject. Hence, we have 12 trials ("independent") of 21 observations

#random generation of the response variable
require(plyr)
posl<-paste("z",1:8,sep="")
mydata$pos<-factor(NA,levels=posl)
    n=nrow(mydata)
    mydata$pos<-replicate(n,sample(posl,1,prob=c(0.05,0.05,0.05,0.4,0.3,0.05,0.05,0.05)))

#strong preference for z3 and z4

##pre-treatment of the above row data, number of time (out of 21) each position was observed
mydata2=ddply(mydata,.(sub,per,pos),summarize,nobs=length(pos),.drop=F)
mydata2[,1:3]=catcolwise(function(x)as.factor(x))(mydata2)
summary(mydata2)

# boxplot of frequencies of occpupancy
require(ggplot2)
mydata2$fobs=mydata2$nobs/21
ggplot(mydata2)+geom_boxplot(aes(pos,fobs))

###chi2 test
nobsT=ddply(mydata,.(pos),summarize,T=length(pos))
nobsT=nobsT[,2]
chisq.test(nobsT)

#bootstrapping of the mean proportions over the 12 replicates
require(boot)
maf=function(data,index){o=ddply(data[index,],.(pos),summarize,mmea=mean(fobs),.drop=F);as.vector(o[,2])}
bootobj=boot(mydata2,maf,R=9999,stype="i")

confint=ddply(mydata2,.(pos),summarize,mean.prop=mean(fobs))
confint$boot.LOW=-999
    confint$boot.UP=-999
for (posi in 1:8){
  try({confint$boot.LOW[posi]<-boot.ci(bootobj,0.95,index=posi,type="bca")$bca[4]},silent=T)
  try({confint$boot.UP[posi]<-boot.ci(bootobj,0.95,index=posi,type="bca")$bca[5]},silent=T)
}

####################### plotting boostraped CI
ggplot(mydata2)+geom_boxplot(aes(pos,fobs))+
  geom_errorbar(data=confint,aes(pos,ymin=mean.prop-boot.LOW,ymax=mean.prop+boot.UP),lty=2,width=0.5)+
  geom_point(data=confint,aes(pos,mean.prop),shape=24,size=2)
```

References of the CI estimations I would like to run:

Glaz, J. and C.P. Sison. 1999. Simultaneous confidence intervals for multinomial proportions. Journal of Statistical Planning and Inference 82:251-262.

Sison, C.P and J. Glaz. 1995. Simultaneous confidence intervals and sample size determination for multinomial proportions. Journal of the American Statistical Association, 90:366-369. Paper available at http://tx.liberal.ntu.edu.tw/~purplewoo/Literature/!Methodology/!Distribution_SampleSize/SimultConfidIntervJASA.pdf

Comment: Welcome to the site.  I edited your post quite a bit to fix the English usage. I also removed your sig line as the site puts in your name automatically.

Comment: Is the 21 at the beginning a typo for 12?

Comment: Thanks dear @PeterFlom . No, I observed each individual 21 times, and I have 12 individuals. I would like to keep this 12 replicates, instead of pooling them, in order to conserve individual to individual variability.

Comment: You may find MultinomailCI package helpful: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MultinomialCI/index.html